# Rails: Values not getting assigned to array when in a do loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have an array called `components`

```
components = [
   {
      :name => "Component 1",
      :order => "1"
   },
   {
      :name => "Component 2",
      :order => "2"
   },
   {
      :name => "Component 3",
      :order => "3"
   },
   {
      :name => "Component 4",
      :order => "4"
   }
]
```

And another array called `subcomponent`

```
subcomponents = [
   {
      :name => "Subcomponent 1A",
      :order => "1A"
   },
   {
      :name => "Subomponent 1B",
      :order => "1B"
   },
   {
      :name => "Component 2A",
      :order => "2A"
    },
   {
      :name => "Component 4A",
      :order => "4A"
   }
]
```

I'm trying to get it so that the subcomponents appear underneath a component object if they are a subcomponent of that object. This is the expected output:

```
components = [
   {
      :name => "Component 1",
      :order => "1",
      :subcomponents => [
         {
            :name => "Subcomponent 1A",
            :order => "1A"
         },
         {
            :name => "Subomponent 1B",
            :order => "1B"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      :name => "Component 2",
      :order => "2",
      :subcomponents => [ 
         {
            :name => "Component 2A",
            :order => "2A"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      :name => "Component 3",
      :order => "3",
      :subcomponent => []
   },
   {
      :name => "Component 4",
      :order => "4",
      :subcomponent => [
         {
            :name => "Component 4A",
            :order => "4A"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I've created a loop to try to do this:

```
components.each do |c|
      c.class.module_eval { attr_accessor :subcomponents}
      c.subcomponents = []

      subcomponents.each do |s|
        if /#{c["order"]}[A-Z]/ =~ s["order"]
          #This is never assigned but it does make it into this statement 
          c.subcomponents << s
        end
      end 

     puts c.subcomponents.to_s # This prints []
end
```

As I've put in my code comments, the subcomponent is never assigned back to the `component.subcomponents` arrays even though the if statement is stepped into.

Am I missing something where the scope of `component.subcomponents` isn't accessible anymore or is at a different scope?

What should I be doing to ensure I can assign value `component.subcomponents`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
components.each do |c|
  c[:subcomponents] = []
  subcomponents.each do |s|
    c[:subcomponents] << s if /#{c[:order]}[A-Z]/ =~ s[:order]
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this work.

```
components.each do |component|
  component[:subcomponents] = []
end

subcomponents.each do |subcomponent|
  order = subcomponent[:order][/\d+/]

  components.each do |component|
    if order == component[:order]
      component[:subcomponents] << subcomponent
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in `O(n)` using this:

```
subcomponent_hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
subcomponents.each do |sc|
  order = sc[:order][/\d+/]
  subcomponent_hash[order] << sc
end

components.each do |c|
  c[:subcomponents] = subcomponent_hash[c[:order]]
end
```